# How do I get this CSS animation with background images to work in this Markdown file?

Tags: html, image, canvas, markdown, css-animations

I want to animate a `<canvas>` by changing the background image over time using the `@keyframes` rule in css. I cannot get the animation to work. I cannot even get the `<canvas>` tag to display a single static image. Could someone please check my code to see where I've gone wrong?

I've tried:

- Testing the same code in a plain HTML file
- Using ".jpg" image files instead of ".png"
- Not using a separate class for the canvas tag. So in this code, I wrote `<canvas class="jump-animation"></canvas>` but I've also tried putting the animation style in the canvas tag and using `<canvas></canvas>` but that also doesn't work

Here's the markdown file:

```
<link href="resources/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<h1>HELLO?!</h1>
<canvas class="jump-animation"></canvas>
```

And here's the style sheet:

```css
canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: contain;

    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.jump-animation {
    -webkit-animation-name: jump;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 7s;

    animation-name: jump;
    animation-duration: 7s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes jump {
    0%      { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame1.png); }
    14%     { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame2.png); }
    28%     { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame3.png); }
    42%     { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame4.png); }
    56%     { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame5.png); }
    80%     { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame6.png); }
    100%    { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame7.png); }
}

@keyframes jump {
    0%      { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame1.png); }
    14%     { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame2.png); }
    28%     { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame3.png); }
    42%     { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame4.png); }
    56%     { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame5.png); }
    80%     { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame6.png); }
    100%    { background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame7.png); }
}

h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

The header with the word "HELLO?!" is just to test to see if the style sheet is being linked properly, which it is. If I change the color for the h1 tag in the style sheet, the markdown file responds to the change.  But nothing I do for the `<canvas>` tag seems to work

It's also rather telling that I cannot even get the `<canvas>` tag to display a *static* image for the background, in Markdown or in HTML, which suggests to me that there's something bigger here that I'm missing

So for instance, in the style sheet, I tried:

```css
canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: contain;
    background: url(resources/jumpAnimation/frame1.png);
}
```

Which had absolutely no effect on the display of the `<canvas>` tag. It was still empty

Answer (score 1):

OHMYGOSHIMDUMB

The style.css style sheet is *in* the "resources" folder.  This means that all of the url's with "resources/" out in front are incorrect.  I need to remove all of the "resources/" parts from out in front of all the links to the images.  Once I did this, all the images loaded properly

Thanks for letting me post this question, even though it was a trivial problem ;)